# How to trigger an event only when check box of jqgrid is selected or checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, asp.net-ajax

I have code implemented for jqgrid, in my code upon selecting each row the count of values will be shown in a jquery data table. It is calculating values even though when I unselect the check box I tried in many ways to solve it but no use. Please help.I am attaching code here for your review.

### Js script:-

```
function callme(fncount, lncount, i, gndr) {
    var grid = $("#ListGrid");
    var s;
    s = jQuery("#ListGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
    alert(s);
    //if (s > 0) {
    var yesrno = $("#ListGrid").find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')
    alert(yesrno);
    if (yesrno == true) {
        $.post('/TodoList/This_is_final', { 'FirstNameCount': fncount, 'LastNameCount': lncount, 'TotalSalary': i, 'GenderCount': gndr }, function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            $('#example').dataTable({

                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [{ "mData": "FirstNamecount" },
                    { "mData": "LastNamecount" },
                    { "mData": "Salary" },
                    { "mData": "Gendercount" }],
                retrieve: true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                paging: false,

            }).fnDestroy();
        });

    }

}
```

### Controller:-

```
 public JsonResult This_is_final(int FirstNameCount, int LastNameCount, int TotalSalary, int GenderCount)
        {
          // Console.WriteLine(b);
           List<Counting> lc = new List<Counting>();
           Counting c = new Counting();
           c.FirstNamecount = Convert.ToInt32(FirstNameCount);
           c.LastNamecount = LastNameCount;
           c.Salary = TotalSalary;
           c.Gendercount = GenderCount;
           //c.lc.Add(c);
           //var data=c.lc.OrderBy(a => a.Salary);
          lc.Add(c);
           //// lc.ToList();

            return Json(lc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

[image: Jqgrid] upon selecting rows of jqgrid the count will be shown in a datatable [image: Jquery datatable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in `jqgrid` `onSelectRow` event like following. Hope this will help you.

```
onSelectRow: function(row, isSelected) {
    var rows = $("#ListGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

    var totalRow = rows.length;
    var totalAmount = 0;

    $.each(rows, function() {
       var rowData = $("#ListGrid").getRowData(this);
       totalAmount += rowData["amount"] * 1;
    });

    dataTable.row($('#example').find('tbody tr')).remove().draw();
    dataTable.row.add([totalRow, totalAmount]).draw();
}
```

#### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/0h95Ltps/3/)

Comment: Hi Azim, Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to add all amount values of jqgrid in the example given by you with onselectall function of jqgrid?